# Fix jQuery table sorter header row in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

So, I have a table I want to sort with the jQuery tablesorter plugin.
If I put everything -- column headers and data into a single table, everything sorts super easy. However, if I have lots of rows in my table, I want the data rows to be in a scolling div. Any ideas on how to fix the header row in place?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have the html/css/js you can share. Would help to see how far you've gotten

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured this one out. (Sorry, didn't have code I could actually paste, and spent the time fixing my code rather than coming up with something I could post.)

What I ended up doing was something like this:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

The problem I had was not having a  in the table I was trying to sort, because I had a different table containing the column headers.

Comment: Did you look at the [write your own widget](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-widgets.html) example?